# gdb how to set breakpoint in dynamic library opened by dlopen

Tags: c++, c, gdb, dlopen

Afternoon,everbody.
I have an application 'test' compiled by main.c . A dynamic liabrary 'libtest.so' which is compiled by test.cpp with '-g'. In main.c I invoke the 'libtest.so' with 'dlopen' . And now I want to  set a breakpoint in test.cpp ,but the gdb never hit it. I do as follow:

*gdb ./test -d /home/lcl/test*

*break test.cpp:35*

*run*

can anybody give me some tips ,thanks!

Comment: thanks to reply me , -d just to point the directory gdb search for. just like dir command

Comment: I tried it. line number 35 just a function name. if I compile test.c with 'gcc -c main.c -o test -ltest -L./'  I can set breakpoint but failed when open with dlopen ...

Comment: yeah, but now I must have supper. I will attach the code later. and thanks  Mantosh Kumar

Comment: Yes, with this little progress you got eligibility to have supper. :)

Comment: I actually have the same problem 2 years later, how did you figure this out ?

Answer (score 3):

You should first verify that `dlopen` is actually succeeding (it's likely that it's not).

To do so:

- set a breakpoint in `main.c` *after* `dlopen`.
- confirm that returned handle is not `NULL`

At that point, GDB should have loaded symbols for `libtest.so`, and `libtest.so` should show up in `info shared` GDB output.

If everything looks good, `info break` should show an active breakpoint in `test.cpp:35` at some address. If that breakpoint is never hit, it's likely that you never actually exercise that line of code.